# Is there an Haskell equivalent of npx?

Tags: haskell

When using Pyhton we have pipx - a tool that makes it easy for users to install and manage applications (especially CLI tools) rather then libraries. For node.js there is npx. Is there a tool for Haskell that offers the same functionality?

1. pipx run "$APP" --example foo" install & update & run all-in-one
2. Apps are installed into isolated environments so that they do not step on each other's toes. (e.g. incompatible dependency requirements)

I know there is one general-purpose option - Docker, but is there anything tailored to Haskell?

**Edit:** the main reason I dislike Docker is that it alters my view of the filesystem. A CLI tool might accept paths via the arguments, the environment and config files and then open them. Reading relative to CWD is also common. If a CLI tool is distributed via Docker, the user has to be aware of the altered filesystem view, which adds cognitive overhead.

Comment: Are you going to ask that question for _every_ programming language in existence?

Comment: Tool recommendation requests are off-topic here. Even if they weren't, this question is pretty low quality; it doesn't show any research effort.

Comment: I think you are looking for `stack`. It download dependencies (including the compiler) in an isolated evironment. `stack install` will install a binary in your path, `stack build` will generate a binary in the project folder `stack run app`  will run the app in the project folder, without installing it globally